# Collect all data from FirebaseDatabse and call notifyDataSetChanged() once

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

in brief: I have a list of users ID and I want to iterate over database and find profiles of those users and put them on the list. But I have a problem as follows:

```
final List<Friend> friendsProfiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final FriendId friendId : friendIds) {
        mUserRef.child(friendId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Get the friend profile
                Friend friend = dataSnapshot.getValue(Friend.class);
                // Add to the list
                friendsProfiles.add(friend);
                // The problem is here, because its called as many times as the size of
                // the friendIds list. loadnewData() contains notifyDataSetChanged()
                mFriendsFragment.loadNewData(friendsProfiles);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    // It gives 0, because it's called before onDatachange()
    // So I can't call loadNewData() here
    Log.d(TAG, updatedFriendsRequestList.size());
```

How to do it in the nice, proper way?

Comment: What is the type of your `friendIds` list?

Comment: I simplified the case in sake of better understanding. In original it contains: String friendId and type of the invitation to friends ("sent" or "received"). So it is basically list of objects that contain 2 strings.

Comment: So basically your `friendIds` list is declared as `List<String> friendIds = new ArrayList<>();`, right?

Comment: No. In this case it is a list of invitations to the friends. It looks like this: `List<FriendRequest> requests= new ArrayList<>();` where FriendRequest is an object that contains `String frienId` and `String requestType` ("sent" or "received") either he sent invitation or received and this determines which layout to use.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. One more thing, please show me how your `friendIds` list is declared. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply count how many you've already loaded, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` only once you've loaded the last one:

```
final List<Friend> friendsProfiles = new ArrayList<>();
for (final FriendId friendId : friendIds) {
    mUserRef.child(friendId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get the friend profile
            Friend friend = dataSnapshot.getValue(Friend.class);
            // Add to the list
            friendsProfiles.add(friend);

            if (friendsProfiles.size() == friendIds.length) {
                mFriendsFragment.loadNewData(friendsProfiles);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors, as they break the logic of your app
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If the list contains 1000 ids, is it ok to add a listener 1000 times?

Comment: That seems like a different question. But all your listeners are short-lived, so I doubt it'll create a problem. If it does (or you're worried enough you want to be sure it doesn't), throttle how often you add a next listener: so add the first 10 or so, and then only add the next one once another completes (or gets cancelled).

Comment: I've got the answer to one of my biggest problems in my today's work from this comment. Thank you!!!! I'll try your solution. +1

Comment: @IoanaP. I know it's awful solution, but I can not find better one. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Thank you, it's simple solution, why it did not come to my mind.. But I will wait, maybe someone post another solution.

Comment: @northenofca I don't have any suggestions. I struggled all day with a similar problem but I'll go with Frank's solution.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You're right with that comment, sorry about that. Just asked the OP about the type of the `friendIds` list. Thanks!