# How to get an object from Firebase only when the previous object is completed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list which is full of user ids like so:

```
List<String> userIds = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I want to loop over this list and get all the corresponding user object from the Firebase database. This is my code:

```
for (String uid : userIds) {
    usersRef.child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            //Create another listener?
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

I know I can use nested listeners but I cannot go this way because my list has over 1000 uids.

How can I get the next user object only when the previous one is completed? I followed Frank van Puffelen's comment from his answer within this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53284983/collect-all-data-from-firebasedatabse-and-call-notifydatasetchanged-once/) but I cannot complete this task. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load them sequentially, just remove the IDs you've gotten from the list.

Something like this:

```
public void getNextUser() {
  if (list.size() > 0) {
    String uid = list.get(0)
    list.remove(0);
    usersRef.child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            getNextUser()
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }
    });
  }
}
```

And then kick it off with:

```
getNextUser();
```